# How do i map a JSON API response that contains an array of objects to an ag-grid table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid

I am wanting to map a response that I get from an API to the `AgGridReact` component. The gist of the page is for the user to enter a stock market symbol and then optionally select dates to find stock prices between two dates. I am able to contact the API just fine. The response I receive is just like the one here [JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkoVW.jpg).
The response is an array containing multiple objects (depending on the search). Where I am having the issue is taking the response and mapping it to an ag-grid-react table.

This is the code for the table headers

```
const columns = [
  { headerName: "Sybmol", field: "symbol" }, 
  { headerName: "Name", field: "name" }, 
  { headerName: "Open", field: "open" }, 
  { headerName: "High", field: "high" }, 
  { headerName: "Low", field: "low" }, 
  { headerName: "Close", field: "close" }, 
  { headerName: "Volumes", field: "volumes" }, 
  { headerName: "Time", field: "time" }, 
]
```

Originally i thought it would work like a normal map function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url, { headers })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.stocks)
    .then(stocks =>
        stocks.map(stock => {
          return{
            sybmol: stock.symbol,
            name: stock.name,
            //etc...
          }
        }))
}, [search, FromDate, ToDate])
```

However, this gives me the error **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Here is the JSON Data as requested

```
   (17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {timestamp: "2020-03-23T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 10.9, …}
1: {timestamp: "2020-03-22T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 10.6526, …}
2: {timestamp: "2020-03-19T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 11.6, …}
3: {timestamp: "2020-03-18T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 14.24, …}
4: {timestamp: "2020-03-17T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 15.785, …}
5: {timestamp: "2020-03-16T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 12.4065, …}
6: {timestamp: "2020-03-15T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 15.3, …}
7: {timestamp: "2020-03-12T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 14.05, …}
8: {timestamp: "2020-03-11T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 16.31, …}
9: {timestamp: "2020-03-10T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 15.82, …}
10: {timestamp: "2020-03-09T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 14.87, …}
11: {timestamp: "2020-03-08T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 15.02, …}
12: {timestamp: "2020-03-05T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 17.54, …}
13: {timestamp: "2020-03-04T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 18.36, …}
14: {timestamp: "2020-03-03T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 19.66, …}
15: {timestamp: "2020-03-02T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 19.05, …}
16: {timestamp: "2020-03-01T14:00:00.000Z", symbol: "AAL", name: "American Airlines Group", industry: "Industrials", open: 19.8, …}
length: 17
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Page Code (Could not include API information as that is private)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, }from 'react';
import './Quote.css';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import SearchStocks from './SearchStocks';
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

function SearchBar(props){
  const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <label className="CheckStocks-SearchBar-Label" htmlFor="search">Search By Symbol:</label>
      <input className="CheckStocks-SearchBar" name="search" id="search" type="search" value={innerSearch} onChange={(e) => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)} />
      
      <Button className="CheckStocks-SearchBar-Button" color="primary" size="lg" id="search-button" type="button" 
              onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)}>
        Search
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

function FromDateSelector(props){
  const [innerDate, setInnerDate] = useState('');
  

  return(
    <div>
      <input type="date" value={innerDate} onChange={(e) => setInnerDate(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerDate)}>Select From Date</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function ToDateSelector(props){
  const [innerDate2, setInnerDate2] = useState('');
  

  return(
    <div>
      <input type="date" value={innerDate2} onChange={(e) => setInnerDate2(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerDate2)}>Select To Date Date</button>
    </div>
  );
}


function GetStocks(search, FromDate, ToDate) {
  

  const [ rowData, setRowData ] = useState([]);
  

  let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const headers = {
    accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer` + //Usually a token as well
  }
  
  let FromDateLink = '?from=' + FromDate
  const url = 'TheAPiUrl' + search + FromDateLink;

  function ApiCall(){
    fetch(url, { headers })
    .then((res) => res.json())
  }

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url, { headers })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.stocks)
    .then(stocks =>
        stocks.map(stock => {
          return{
            sybmol: stock.symbol,
            name: stock.name,
            //etc...
          }
        }))
}, [search, FromDate, ToDate])

  return{
    rowData,
  }
  
}


function Quote() {
  
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [FromDate, setFromDate] = useState('');
  const [ToDate, setToDate] = useState('');
  const { rowData } = GetStocks(search, FromDate, ToDate);
  

  return(
    <div>
      <h1 className="Quote-Title">Quote Page</h1>
      <div className="Quote-Search-Box">
        <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
        <FromDateSelector onSubmit={setFromDate} />
        <ToDateSelector onSubmit={setToDate} />
        <h1>{search}</h1>
        <br></br>
        <h1>{FromDate}</h1>
        <h1>{ToDate}</h1>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Quote;
```

My first question on stack overflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you add the json data to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the returned response from the API request into your component's state.

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
```

And on your `GetStocks` method, you will need to update the state after the response is returned:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url, { headers })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.stocks)
    .then(stocks =>
      const res = stocks.map(stock => ({
        sybmol: stock.symbol,
        name: stock.name,
        //etc...
      }));
      setData(res);
    );
}, [search, FromDate, ToDate]);
```

Finally, on the rendered `AgGridReact` itself, you will need to pass the data to the `rowData` props:

```
<AgGridReact
  rowData={data}>
  // other props such as columnDefs
</AgGridReact>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However i am getting an error on the  'const' line saying 'expected { '

Comment: @RileyHead ah.. I have a missing parenthesis. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I was able to get my question solved by a friend. However, your answer helped a little. I'll mark it as correct. Thanks